# Is there a way to keep data retrieved via IMPORTXML (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have many rows that each have a URL to retrieve data from using IMPORTXML. Additionally, I have numerous columns of IMPORTXML cells from each row's URL.

Whenever I perform actions that shifts a cell's row/column (eg. deleting a previous row/column), all cells that shift reperform the IMPORTXML function, leading to a whole page of "Loading..." cells. Also, it seems like all the IMPORTXML functions are reperformed each time the spreadsheet is loaded up.

I've tried webscraping with Google App Script instead, but I am not familiar enough with XML to know how to do that.

Is there a way to keep information retrieved via IMPORTXML static such that it does not refresh its information on each load / shift?

Thank you!

Comment: In your situation, how about the following 2 patterns? 1. `IMPORTXML` is put into a cell using a script and the retrieved values are copied as the values without the formula. 2. Although I have no information about your expected values from your expected URL, directly retrieve your expected values from the URL using UrlFetchApp with a script. For both patterns, when you want to update the values, you can do it by executing the script. Although this is the methodology because of no information about your actual situation, if those were not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer as a community wiki, since a proper answer has been provided in the comments section.

According to documentation, when using `IMPORTXML` function:

> If you delete and re-add cells or overwrite the cells with the same
> formula, it triggers a refresh of the functions.

As you mentioned above, you want the retrieved data to remain static. In this case you can use `UrlFetchApp` with Apps Script to retrieve the desired values and set them in your Google Sheet.

By setting triggers, you can get updates from the URLs at a certain time, so that the information is not reloaded every time you update your Sheet but only when you specify in the trigger.

#### References:

- [IMPORTXML Data Freshness](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12188454?hl=en#:%7E:text=cause%20a%20throttle.-,Data%20Freshness,-To%20ensure%20users)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)